# Unable to create mbean: Could not create provider JDBCDataSource

Tags: jdbc, ant, weblogic11g

```
 <target name="createpool">
  <wlconfig username="${username}" password="${password}" url="${adminURL}">
    <query domain="${domainName}" type="Server" name="${targetserver}" property="x" /> 
        <create type="JDBCConnectionPool" name="${JDBCConnectionPool.name}" >
           <set attribute="CapacityIncrement" value="1"/>
           <set attribute="DriverName" value="${database.driver}"/>
           <set attribute="InitialCapacity" value="0"/>
           <set attribute="MaxCapacity" value="10"/>
           <set attribute="Password" value="${database.password}"/>
           <set attribute="Properties" value="user=${database.user}"/>
           <set attribute="RefreshMinutes" value="0"/>
           <set attribute="ShrinkPeriodMinutes" value="15"/>
           <set attribute="ShrinkingEnabled" value="true"/>
           <set attribute="TestConnectionsOnRelease" value="false"/>
           <set attribute="TestConnectionsOnReserve" value="true"/>
           <set attribute="TestTableName" value="SYSTABLES"/>
           <set attribute="URL" value="${database.url}"/>
           <set attribute="Targets" value="${x}" />
        </create>
        <create type="JDBCDataSource" name="${JDBCDataSource.name}" >
           <set attribute="JNDIName" value="${JNDI.name}"/>
           <set attribute="PoolName" value="${Pool.name}"/>
           <set attribute="Targets" value="${targetserver}" />
        </create>
  </wlconfig>
 </target>
```

Please provide Solution to solve this problem as after running this ant script its giving me Unable to create mbean: Could not create provider JDBCDataSource.

Comment: Do you have more details with the error message ? (You can run ant with `-verbose` option to make it verbose). Did you setup your environment as recommended here : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13706/ant_tasks.htm#WLPRG142 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <query domain="${domainName}" type="Server" name="${targetserver}" property="targetserv"/>

  <set attribute="Targets" value="${targetserv}" />
```

By doing these changes it worked fine